# Will this sudo rule allow a user to update the system and nothing more?

Tags: updates, security, sudo, aptitude

I want to design a sudo rule that will allow the user `ricardo` to update the system using `aptitude`, but prevent him from using sudo to run any other command (he's a problem user). Are there any pitfalls to this rule that I'm missing?

```
ricardo  ALL=(root) /usr/bin/aptitude
```

Ricardo only uses `aptitude`, not `apt-get`. Also, I don't have Ubuntu installed anywhere at the moment, so I understand that `/usr/bin/aptitude` might not be the exact right file to allow.

If there are pitfalls to this rule, how can I improve it?

Comment: the only pitfall I see is that, if he's a problem user, he can mess up the system with aptitude all the same.

Comment: @roadmr True. Although still not perfect, would this command be a bit more suitable, but only allowing the user to update, but not remove packages?
`ricardo  ALL=(root) /usr/bin/aptitude update, /usr/bin/aptitude dist-upgrade`

Comment: Looks like you answered your own question :) what you posted seems to work and it only lets the user run aptitude with the specified parameters.

Comment: @roadmr Should I post that as an answer or let you work it into yours?

Comment: you found out the answer, so I suggest you post it as an answer and then accept it. I did nothing but provide feedback.

Comment: @roadmr Done. I added some information from aptitude's [man page](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/lucid/man8/aptitude.8.html) about `safe-upgrade` vs `full-upgrade`, since I can see someone wanting to allow a user to perform a `safe-upgrade` but not a `full-upgrade`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This command will restrict the user from using `aptitude` for anything but updating the repository cache and performing a safe upgrade of the system.

```
ricardo ALL=(root) /usr/bin/aptitude update, /usr/bin/aptitude safe-upgrade
```

A similar command will allow the user to perform a full upgrade, but nothing more:

```
ricardo ALL=(root) /usr/bin/aptitude update, /usr/bin/aptitude full-upgrade
```

Per [aptitude's documentation (10.04)](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/lucid/man8/aptitude.8.html), `safe-upgrade`:

> Upgrades installed packages to their most recent version. Installed
>              packages will not be removed unless they are unused

In contrast, `full-upgrade`:

> Upgrades installed packages to their most recent version, removing
>              or installing packages as necessary. This command is less
>              conservative than safe-upgrade and thus more likely to perform
>              unwanted actions. However, it is capable of upgrading packages that
>              safe-upgrade cannot upgrade.

Use your best judgement for which the user should be allowed to run. If you're unsure, use the first rule, which only allows `safe-upgrade`.

Note that if you want to allow a user to install packages (which greatly reduces any benefit to security, but hypothetically), you need to include a `*` after the `aptitude` command, i.e.

```
ricardo ALL=(root) /usr/bin/aptitude update, /usr/bin/aptitude safe-upgrade, /usr/bin/aptitude install *
```

Otherwise, you will receive an error message that user `ricardo` is not allowed to run the command `/usr/bin/aptitude install <package_name>`.

Comment: fantastic, remember to accept this answer so it gets marked as the correct one.

Comment: @roadmr Done. I modified my answer to include information about installing packages as well, because I ran into such a problem while tinkering in a VM.

Comment: I have something like this setup as well, but I'm not confident that aptitude does not offer the user any interactive prompts to fork arbitrary commands/shells. Can anybody confirm?

Answer (score 4):

You can use `sudo -l` to see which commands a user is allowed to run. For instance, to see which commands ricardo can run:

```
sudo -ll -U ricardo
```

to see whether he can run aptitude,

```
sudo -ll -U ricardo /usr/bin/aptitude
```

this will either print the command name as it's expanded by sudo, or exit with code 1 if the user is not allowed to use the command.

This should work in any recent debian-based system for you to test; the syntax is not Ubuntu-specific.

source: [man sudo](http://linux.die.net/man/8/sudo)

Comment: Although this command is helpful, is it related to my question in a way I'm missing?

Comment: with this command you can see for yourself exactly what the user will be allowed to run :)

Answer (score 2):

I can not actually see anything *wrong* with that sudoers line.  Unfortunately, I have not messed around with `sudo`'s configuration settings that much, so in that case, my advice may not be reliable.  Fortunately, what I *can* do is give you a line that I do know is safe:

```
ricardo ALL=/usr/bin/aptitude
```

This line is guaranteed to only let ricardo execute `aptitude` as root, as long as ricardo is not a member of a sudo-enabled group, such as `sudo` or `admin`.

Source: [8 Ways to Tweak and Configure Sudo on Ubuntu - How-to Geek](http://www.howtogeek.com/116757/8-ways-to-tweak-and-configure-sudo-on-ubuntu/).

Comment: The command I posted is identical to yours, except that my command won't allow ricardo to run `aptitude` as any other user. Yours might have the same restriction, but the command I posted makes it explicit.